# Получить id пользователя VK

Tags: vkontakte-api

Подскажите способ быстро получить id пользователя ВК, который зашел на мой сайт.

У меня есть кнопка, и по нажатию на нее должно появиться окно ВК, и после разрешения я должен получить id или же сразу имя и урл к картинке аватара.

Все должно быть без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.init({
    apiId: код приложения
});
function authInfo(response) {
  if (response.session) {
      console.log(response.session.mid);
  }
}
VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo);
VK.Auth.login(authInfo);
</script>
```

Чтобы получить доступ к АРІ нужно зарегистрировать свое приложения.

Comment: Это сейчас еще работает?

Answer (score 2):

Я рекомендую обратиться к [документации](http://vk.com/dev/).

Конкретно так функция, которая вам нужна - [account.getProfileInfo](http://vk.com/dev/account.getProfileInfo)

Comment: account.getProfileInfo не имеет урл аватара

Comment: Это только для standalone-приложений. Нужен [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get) с [правильными полями](https://vk.com/dev/fields).

Comment: @Etki проблема в том что сначала мне нужно узнать id пользователя

Comment: @M11 если у вас есть токен, то отправляете users.get() без указания id пользователя и он вам вернет данные для текущего юзера.