# Как узнать ID пользователя, заходившего на мой сайт?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Есть ли способ/метод узнать ID пользователя ВКонтакте, который открыл страницу на моём сайте? Желательно без установки всяких приложений.

Я точного алгоритма работы не знаю, но часто, если заходишь на разные сайты, есть возможность комментировать - то есть на них каким-то образом считывается ID?

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Сайт об id не узнаёт, поскольку пользователь не давал согласия "представиться этому сайту". Он может сделать это только явно. В теории.

На практике иногда появляются разнообразные схемы, обманом вынуждающие пользователей войти через ВК (пользователь может об этом даже не узнать) и тем самым предоставить сайту id профиля. По очевидным причинам, рассматривать подробности таких схем я не буду. Среди веб-разработчиков их рассматривают, как уязвимости, администрация ВК о них знает.

Штатная форма комментариев ВК не взаимодействует с серверной частью сайта вовсе. Можете проверить сами, поставив её на статичную страницу и опубликовав. "Опознание" проводит браузер клиента, запрашивая форму комментариев с доменов ВК. По сути, это открытие страницы ВК через фрейм, а Same Origin Policy в браузерах не даст вам доступ к информации в этом фрейме.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете, например, установить кнопку, по нажатию на которую будете получать `id` пользователя. Подобный вопрос был задан в [этом топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429214/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-vk?rq=1).

Насчет незаконных способов была небольшая статейка на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/228617/) и еще на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/234067/), также [Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/blog/webmaster/21745) внес свою лепту.

Answer (score 0):

Id пользователей Вконтакте, как правило, получают через api Вконтакте. Может эта ссылка поможет решить задачу?
https://vk.com/dev/openapi